# Rails 3: update method redirection problem

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Trying to build a CMS for a blog using rails 3.
In my routes.rb...

```
namespace :admin do  
  resources :posts  
  root :to => "home#index"  
end
```

In Admin::PostsController...

```
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
      format.html { redirect_to(@post,
                  :notice => 'Post was successfully updated.')}
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors,
                    :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I had to change the first line of admin/_form.html.erb due to a previous 'undefined method' error that was driving me crazy. Was trying to point the browser to a nonexistent "post_path".

```
<%= form_for(@post, :url => admin_posts_path(@post)) do |f| %>
```

All other methods for posts are working as expected. Upon form submission (update) - the rails server...

```
Started POST "/admin/posts.1"
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/admin/posts.1"):
```

First, curious as to why it is using POST instead of PUT for the update.

Second, I can't figure out why the URL is being interpreted as "/admin/posts.1" and how to fix it.

Has anyone else run into this problem? (and yes, I am following the rubyonrails.org guides closely to help me). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Changed `admin_posts_path(@post)` to `admin_post_path(@post)` per [theIV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124674/theiv).

the rails server...
     `NoMethodError (undefined method 'post_url' for    #<Admin::PostsController:0x00000102b26ff8>):
    app/controllers/admin/posts_controller.rb:55:in 'block (2 levels) in update'
    app/controllers/admin/posts_controller.rb:53:in 'update'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should be hitting `admin_post_path(@post)`, not `admin_posts_path(@post)`.

Look at the table that lists all of the helpers created for your routes on [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing).

EDIT: Also, have you tried the array style of urls? It's pretty convenient.

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @post]) do |f| %>
```

EDIT 2: My guess as to "undefined method post_url" is from your update action here:

```
format.html { redirect_to(@post,
              :notice => 'Post was successfully updated.')}
```

It needs to be namespaced as well:

```
format.html { redirect_to([:admin, @post],
              :notice => 'Post was successfully updated.')}
```

Comment: this throws a new error...  ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/posts", :id=>#<Post id: nil, author: nil, title: nil, subtitle: nil, content: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}): ...

Comment: this does fix the url, but: "undefined local variable or method `post'"

Comment: Can you update your question with the context surrounding that new error for "undefined local variable"?

Comment: woops, fixed the undefined local variable. editing post to show new error: "undefined method `post_url'"